# Find all integers n such that $\;\frac{n^2-9}{n^2-5n+4}$ is an integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all integers such that $\;\dfrac{n^2-9}{n^2-5n+4}\;$ is an integer.

I am really struggling to figure this out. I can tell that -3,3, and 5 are solutions but I don't know how to show that these are the only solutions or if they even are the only solutions.

Comment: Sorry- show all integers such that the fraction is an integer?

Comment: I think he meant $n^2 - 9$ **divides**  $n^2 - 5n + 4$. Knuth uses a notation very nearly like the one in the problem, except using a backslash for "divides".

Comment: @Mark: I thought of that, but the solutions given rule it out (and we now know what was intended).

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Divide it out:

$$1+\frac{5n-13}{n^2-5n+4}\;.$$

This is an integer if and only if

$$\frac{5n-13}{n^2-5n+4}\tag{1}$$

is an integer. But the denominator of $(1)$ increases faster than the numerator, so there’s an upper bound on $|n|$ beyond which it can’t be an integer. Find that upper bound, and you can check the finite number of possibilities below it; it isn’t terribly big.

Answer (score 6):

The denominator is $(n-1)(n-4)$. If $n^2\ne 9$, we must have that $n-4$ divides $n^2-9$.

Note that $\frac{n^2-9}{n-4}=n+4+\frac{7}{n-4}$. So the only candidates are those $n$ such that $n-4$ divides $7$. That gives the short list $n=5$, $n=3$, $n=11$, and $n=-3$. Test them all.

Answer (score 2):

Another, shorter (than my other answer) answer again only using divisibility.

This factors as $\frac{(n-3)(n+3)}{(n-4)(n-1)}$. Note that $n$ cannot be $4$ or $1$. The factors $(n-3)$ and $(n-4)$ are relatively prime, so $(n-4)$ must divide the numerator's other factor $(n+3)$.

These numbers are $7$ apart. Their gcd must divide $7$ so it is either $1$ or $7$, but their gcd is $|n-4|$ (remember that $(n-4)$ divides into $(n+3)$). This leaves four possible solutions.

- $n-4=1\implies n=5$
- $n-4=-1\implies n=3$
- $n-4=7\implies n=11$
- $n-4=-7\implies n=-3$

They all check out in the larger rational expression as yielding integers except $n=11$.

Answer (score 0):

Longer, but using only divisibility considerations:

This factors as $\frac{(n-3)(n+3)}{(n-4)(n-1)}$. Note $n$ cannot be $1$ or $4$.

So $|n-1|\geq1$, and if $p$ is a prime dividing $n-1$, then $p$ has to divide $n-3$ or $n+3$. So mod $p$, either $n\equiv1\equiv3$ or $n\equiv1\equiv-3$. Either way, $p$ must be $2$, and $n-1=\pm2^k$ for some $k\geq0$.

$$\frac{(\pm2^k-2)(\pm2^k+4)}{(\pm2^k-3)(\pm2^k)}$$

Now we see $k$ can't be $4$ or more, or else the denominator is divisible by $16$ and the numerator is not. So there are two ($\pm$) cases for each of $k=0,1,2,3$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(\pm1-2)(\pm1+4)}{(\pm1-3)(\pm1)}&&\frac{(\pm2-2)(\pm2+4)}{(\pm2-3)(\pm2)}&&\frac{(\pm4-2)(\pm4+4)}{(\pm4-3)(\pm4)}&&\frac{(\pm8-2)(\pm8+4)}{(\pm8-3)(\pm8)}
\end{align}$$

There are eight options to check.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{5}{2}&&0&&4&&\frac{9}{5}\\
\frac{-9}{4}&&\frac{4}{-5}&&0&&\frac{5}{11}
\end{align}$$
The integers happened for $$n=2^1+1=3$$ $$n=2^2+1=5$$  $$n=-2^2+1=-3$$